# Suggestion about using a database type

Tags: vb.net

My problem is I need to develop a sales application to be used on 5 computers.  The database needs to stay on a main computer and other computers should connect with that over LAN.
I donot want to use SQL Server as it is too complicated to give permissions, setting up firewalls etc. for the end user.

Is that any type of database that could serve my purpose, without giving sharing violation error?

Comment: This is more a question for dba.stackexchange but I doubt you will find 'an answer' to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options either you can go for Server Client DB like MySQL or you can try embedded databases like vista db(These are less complicated).
However for better performance its better to use a proper server client db.